# How to get the content of a string inside two distinct characters in regular intervals in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's assume we have a string named **str**, which is defined as :

```
const str = `
  ( Find this & ( this ) )
`
```

It may not be clear to you, so let me clear it. Our aim is to find the data between **(** & **)**, and alert it ( I personally like to use **replace()**, since I have not worked that much with **match()** or **matchAll()**. So, please pardon me. ). So, here is my regex solution :

```
const find = (str) => {
  str.replace(/\(([\S\s]*?)\)/gm, (_, a) => {
    alert(a)
  }
}
```

So, now I do :

```
find(str)
// => Find this & ( this

/* Expected Result */

//  1) => this
//  2) => Find this & ( this )
```

So, you might have understood that I am having problems with regular repeatation of distint characters. My regex catches up the first **(** , and also the first **)**, and alerts the content between them. But the thing I want is defined below :

> Find between the first **(** maintaining recursion of **(** as well as **)**, which lies between the last **)**
>
> Doesn't matter how many **(** 's comes between **(** and **)**, it should maintain the flow until the last **)** is reached. It's like being in pairs and maintaing it.

More detailed e.g.

```
const str = `
 Find (
  I feel ( 
    lucky ( enough )
  )
 )
`
find(str) 
// 1) => I feel ( lucky ( enough ) )
// 2) => lucky ( enough )
// 3) => enough
```

But actually what I need is in reversed order i.e. the output will be :

```
// 1) => enough
// 2) => lucky ( enough )
// 3) => I feel ( lucky ( enough ) )
```

So, can you help me to solve this problem ? Can this be done ? If yes can you explain me how ?

Comment: maybe setInterval(function, timeout)?

Comment: @Zydnar Please add an example

Comment: Ok, I see you don't mean intervals of time right?

Comment: @Zydnar No, I didn't mean intervals of time.

Comment: What you need is regex groups not fancy functions Try here, you have there legend and you can generate js code at the end https://regex101.com/r/3wF2me/1

Comment: I don't think you can do this with regex, you should look into **balanced parentheses algorithm**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with simple regular expressions. They are either greedy (try to find the longest possible string with your expression) or non-greedy (trying to find the shortest possible string with your expression).
A more fitting approach would be recursion and setting up a function like this:

```
function getTextInParens(text, index=0) {
    const result = []
    let level = 0
    let innerText = ''
    for (let i = index; i < text.length; i++) {
        if (text[i] == '(' && level++ == 0) {
            result.push(...getTextInParens(text, i+1))
        } else if (level > 0) {
            if (text[i] == ')' && --level == 0) {
                result.push(innerText)
                innerText = ''
            } else {
                innerText += text[i]
            }
        } else if (text[i] == ')') break
    }
    return result
}
```

I'll try to go through it step by step:

```
function getTextInParens(text, index=0) {
    // Initialize variables
    const result = []
    let level = 0
    let innerText = ''

    // Loop through all the characters in your string, starting
    // at index
    for (let i = index; i < text.length; i++) {
        // If we hit a '(', increase the level by 1
        if (text[i] == '(' && level++ == 0) {
            // If we hit the first '(' in our part of the string
            // recursively add the inner '(...)' parts in the rest
            // of the string
            result.push(...getTextInParens(text, i+1))
        } else if (level > 0) {
            // If we hit a ')' decrese the level by one
            if (text[i] == ')' && --level == 0) {
                // If the level is 0 (the first '(' was closed again)
                // push the currently saved string into our results
                result.push(innerText)
                // And reset the string in case a new () group appears later
                innerText = ''
            } else {
                // Otherwise, if the level is still > 0 (we are still
                // between (..), keep copying the text
                innerText += text[i]
            }
        } else if (text[i] == ')') break
        // If we find a ')' at level 0, we must be in an inner recursion and the
        // outer group just closed (or we have a malformed string).
        // this will be handled by the function that called us, so stop
    }

    // Return the collected results
    return result
}
```

For a string like `'Find (some(data)(between(parens))) and(some(more))'` this would result in:

```
[
  0: "data"
  1: "parens"
  2: "between(parens)"
  3: "some(data)(between(parens))"
  4: "more"
  5: "some(more)"
]
```

This also highlights the property of recursive functions, that their **innermost instances finish first**. Hence the innermost strings between **(** and **)** appearing first in the array.